# Append a custom node in kendo tree view using angular

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-treeview

I am using Kendo tree with angular. Initially  data will load as tree structure . After that, If we click on any parent node,an input box should appear below to that    node for entering custom data. This is my requirement. Somebody please help.

Comment: Which KendoUI version are you referring to? The one for AngularJS (1.x) or Angular (2+)?

Comment: "@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "^3.0.3",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^1.2.0",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-layout": "^3.1.2",
    "@progress/kendo-angular-treeview": "^2.3.1",
    "@progress/kendo-theme-default": "^2.56.0",
    "@progress/kendo-ui": "^2018.3.926",

Comment: @Philipp use angular 5